# Amazon Polly doesn't speak

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-polly

environment

- Angular11.2

  Spring Boot2.4.5

  EC2(Ubuntu20.04) with snd-aloop

I implement Amazon Polly based on AWS sdk for java 2.0. It speaks in local environment, but in production(EC2) it doesn't although no errors occur. Source is as follows:

```
    @GetMapping("/sound/{chinese}")
    public void getSound(@PathVariable("chinese") String chinese) throws IOException {
       
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_NAME);
        final String accessKey = rb.getString("pollyAccessKey");
        final String secretKey = rb.getString("pollySecretKey");
        AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);
        final String REGION = rb.getString("region");

        try {
            PollyClient polly = PollyClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                .region(Region.of(REGION))
                .build();

            DescribeVoicesRequest describeVoiceRequest = DescribeVoicesRequest.builder()
                    .languageCode("cmn-CN")
                    .engine("standard")
                    .build();

            DescribeVoicesResponse describeVoicesResult = polly.describeVoices(describeVoiceRequest);
            Voice voice = describeVoicesResult.voices().get(0);
            InputStream stream = synthesize(polly, chinese, voice, OutputFormat.MP3);  
            AdvancedPlayer player = new AdvancedPlayer(stream, javazoom.jl.player.FactoryRegistry.systemRegistry().createAudioDevice());
            player.play();
            polly.close();
        } catch (PollyException | JavaLayerException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


 public static InputStream synthesize(PollyClient polly, String text, Voice voice, OutputFormat format) throws IOException {
        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthReq = SynthesizeSpeechRequest.builder()
                .text(text)
                .voiceId(voice.id())
                .outputFormat(format)
                .build();

        ResponseInputStream<SynthesizeSpeechResponse> synthRes = polly.synthesizeSpeech(synthReq);
        return synthRes;
    }
```

I have spent around a week trying to solve this, but it doesn't work.
I have no idea anymore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "It speaks in local environment, but in production(EC2) it doesn't", are you referring to sound coming out of the computer's speaker? This will not work if the `player.play()` code is running on the Amazon EC2 instance, since there is no sound hardware and no way to send it 'back' to your computer. If you have a web-based front-end, you could have the browser play the sound from a file retrieved from Amazon S3.

Comment: As you guess, this app has web-based front-end(Angular). And I'm going to implement based on your opinion as follows:
①Make a file containing inputstream data on S3 from java.
②Implement play function on Angular.
give me some time.